# Is this voting question appropiate?

Tags: discussion

After watching the documentary [Hacking Democracy](http://www.hackingdemocracy.com/) and seeing how easy it was to modify/exploit the voting machine/system. What would be the way to create the most secure voting system possible?

This system must take following points of consideration;

- Physical (on location) Voting
- Remote (Absentee) Voting
- Voter Identification
- Fraud Prevention
- Ballot Counting

Comment: According to [a decision](https://www.bundesverfassungsgericht.de/pressemitteilungen/bvg09-019.html) by the constitutional court in Germany, the voting must be verifiable without expert knowledge. The ruling was very clear that "verified by experts" is not sufficient for a democratic election. (The government argued in vain that an official expert group had certified, that the voting computers had not been manipulated).

Comment: And of course there is the requirement, that a voter must not be able to proof, how he or she has voted, unless there is a extremely good reason (e. g. a tiny fraction of absent votes by people who would not be able to participate in the election otherwise).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Designing a secure voting system is a very difficult topic. It's still the subject of much ongoing research. The question as you propose it is far too broad: whole books could be written on the topic.

Feel free to ask reasonably-scoped questions on that topic, the subject is squarely on-topic.

(Despite the name, IT Security is not just about computers, it's about information security in general. Even that restriction is more of a historical accident than a deliberate decision, and the opening to security in other contexts has been debated now and then.)

Comment: I agree both with that it is ontopic, and that it is too broad as stated. @DigitalFire, I might suggest to start with a more basic question: What are the points of consideration / basic requirements, when considering a digital voting system? I don't think that you enumerated all of them; then again, NealMcb is our resident elections expert.